# Facebook request form not working in HTML

Tags: facebook

I am using facebook request form for my facebook iframe fanpage,

I am using below code for this

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script><script>
         FB.init({ 
            appId:"APP_ID", cookie:true, 
            status:true, xfbml:true 
         });
      </script>
     <fb:serverFbml width="760px">
  <script type="text/fbml">
    <fb:fbml>
      <fb:serverFbml style="width: 755px;">  
     <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:fbml>
            <fb:request-form
                action="<URL for post invite action, see fb:request-form docs for details>"
                method="POST"
                invite="true"
                type="XFBML"
                content="This is a test invitation from XFBML test app
                <fb:req-choice url="see fb:req-choice docs for details."
                    label="Ignore the Facebook test app!" />
             ">

                <fb:multi-friend-selector
                    showborder="false"
                    actiontext="Invite your friends to use Facebook." />
                    </fb:request-form>
         </fb:fbml>
    </script>
</fb:serverFbml>
   </fb:fbml>
  </script>
</fb:serverFbml>
```

The code was working ok earlier around 15-20 days back, now the same is not working. Now only loading frame appears instead of list of friends.

Please suggest how to overcome this issue?

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 0):

this works (for the time being): http://www.ajado.com/blog/embedding-a-xfbml-facebook-friend-invite-request-form-javascript-only/

however, i did not find a way to get this part working:

```
<fb:req-choice url="see fb:req-choice docs for details."
                    label="Ignore the Facebook test app!" />
             ">
```